# Initialise NTFS-Filesystem from old $MFT

Tags: filesystems, partition, ntfs, partition-table

I lost a partition table with one partition formatted as NTFS. `testdisk` and `parted` don't work (due to another mistake), but I could restore the filesystem tree using [RecuperaBit](https://github.com/Lazza/RecuperaBit). Unfortunately, this program cannot yet restore compressed data, except for some files called $MFT, and some others starting with $.

So, it is possible to assemble those information, and initialise a new ntfs-filesystem with those to enable native access to the data? The filesystem tree is complete, and exactly the same it used to be.

**Edit:**
A Hex-Dump of the first 1024 Bytes:

```
$ head -c 1024 \$MFT | od -A x -t x1z -v
000000 46 49 4c 45 30 00 03 00 36 14 09 05 00 00 00 00  >FILE0...6.......<
000010 01 00 01 00 38 00 01 00 98 01 00 00 00 04 00 00  >....8...........<
000020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000030 1a 00 54 94 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 60 00 00 00  >..T.........`...<
000040 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 18 00 00 00  >........H.......<
000050 28 f1 05 f0 ff 41 d2 01 28 f1 05 f0 ff 41 d2 01  >(....A..(....A..<
000060 28 f1 05 f0 ff 41 d2 01 28 f1 05 f0 ff 41 d2 01  >(....A..(....A..<
000070 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000080 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000090 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 68 00 00 00  >........0...h...<
0000a0 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 4a 00 00 00 18 00 01 00  >........J.......<
0000b0 05 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 28 f1 05 f0 ff 41 d2 01  >........(....A..<
0000c0 28 f1 05 f0 ff 41 d2 01 28 f1 05 f0 ff 41 d2 01  >(....A..(....A..<
0000d0 28 f1 05 f0 ff 41 d2 01 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00  >(....A...@......<
0000e0 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >.@..............<
0000f0 04 03 24 00 4d 00 46 00 54 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..$.M.F.T.......<
000100 80 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 01 00 40 00 00 00 01 00  >....H.....@.....<
000110 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f 06 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000120 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 68 00 00 00 00 00  >@.........h.....<
000130 00 00 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 68 00 00 00 00 00  >..h.......h.....<
000140 32 80 06 00 00 0c 00 00 b0 00 00 00 48 00 00 00  >2...........H...<
000150 01 00 40 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..@.............<
000160 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >........@.......<
000170 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  >. ..............<
000180 08 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 21 02 ef 51 00 00 00 00  >........!..Q....<
000190 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  >................<
0001a0 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 31 40 00 00 0c 00 04 9c  >........1@......<
0001b0 b0 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 01 00 40 00 00 00 05 00  >....P.....@.....<
0001c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0001d0 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00  >@........ ......<
0001e0 08 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0001f0 31 01 ff ff 0b 11 01 ff 00 00 01 00 00 20 1a 00  >1............ ..<
000200 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000210 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000220 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000230 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000240 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000250 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000260 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000270 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000280 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000290 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0002a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0002b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0002c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0002d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0002e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0002f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000300 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000310 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000320 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000330 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000340 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000350 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000360 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000370 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000380 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
000390 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0003a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0003b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0003c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0003d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0003e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >................<
0003f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1a 00  >................<
```

and the boot-records (I hope at least)

```
> allparts
Partition #0 -> Partition (NTFS, 1.82 TB, 4706 files, Recoverable, Offset: 2048, Offset (b): 1048576, Sec/Clus: 8, MFT offset: 6293504, MFT mirror offset: 2064)
Partition #1 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 316980352, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #2 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 6 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 152503816, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #3 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 79517584, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #4 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 2 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 9717656, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #5 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 151669368, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #6 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 3 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 628571568, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #7 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 2 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 395066792, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #8 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 15 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 1953514624, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #9 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 3 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 662340344, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #10 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 302860720, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #11 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 10357512, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #12 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 77430456, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #13 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 2 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 85578480, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #14 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 2 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 10767168, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #15 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 3 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 9717856, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #16 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 77101768, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #17 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 4 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 1953514608, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #18 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 154535088, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #19 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 7725240, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #20 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 3 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 153627072, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #21 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 3 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 10357624, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #22 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 716195416, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #23 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 6514936, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #24 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 2 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 98269952, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #25 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 716141024, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #26 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 6820112, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #27 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 2 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 716178792, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #28 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 395876840, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #29 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 2 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 408808056, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #30 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 153921904, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #31 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 2 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 10768552, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #32 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 621608448, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #33 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 716169080, MFT mirror offset: None)
Partition #34 -> Partition (NTFS, ??? b, 1 files, Offset: None, Offset (b): None, Sec/Clus: None, MFT offset: 154558208, MFT mirror offset: None)
```

Comment: “except for some files called $MFT, and some others starting with $” Those are not compressed files, otherwise RecuperaBit would not have extracted them.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Ok, but can I put those together somehow to initialise a ntfs-filesystem with access to the lost data?
All other files have a size of 0 bytes (after ´restore 0 5`-command), and I got for each file an error message ("Cannot restore compressed $Data attribute(s)").
Can I add some further information for clarification?

Comment: You would need to tell us if some boot records are found by RecuperaBit and a hex dump of the first 1024KB of the $MFT file would surely help. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Ok, I hope, I added those data, you need. If not, please add the commands I need to execute. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: The first entry of the MFT looks OK. You mentioned that Testdisk does not work. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: Well, I haven't waited for a whole deep search yet, just till about 25% of the total cylinders. Hopefully, that's the reason it haven't found a partition with the right file system. I'll go for a run, and hope this solves the problem.

Comment: You haven't posted the last lines of the RecuperaBit log before the prompt, however it is likely that there is a backup NTFS boot sector at the end of the drive. So you need to scan it 100% with Testdisk in order to find it. If this is the case, please confirm it so we can answer the question properly.

Comment: Well, those lines are already gone, the `bash`-cache isn't large enough. But `testdisk` just stoped checking the filesystem - and it actually found the right partition. I'm currently backing up the whole partition, before I'm rewriting the partition table again. So - thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this program cannot yet restore compressed data, except for some files called $MFT, and some others starting with $.

I created RecuperaBit and I confirm it cannot read files stored with NTFS compression. Please note that there is no exception: `$MFT` is the file holding the master file table (all metadata files start with `$` and they are not compressed, but some of them are sparse).

Your goal:

> initialise a new ntfs-filesystem with those to enable native access to the data

Would not sound feasible if the MFT was actually damaged. However, you should note that it probably isn't. Your hex dump shows that the first entry (the most important one) is just fine. Most likely, the following are good as well.

What you need to do is restore the partition table and pick up at least one NTFS boot sector. Usually, the backup boot sector can be recovered easily because it's at the end of the drive.

Your output shows the exact size of the file system. That number was read from a boot sector, so you know it's still there:

```
Partition #0 -> Partition (NTFS, 1.82 TB, 4706 files, Recoverable, Offset: 2048, Offset (b): 1048576, Sec/Clus: 8, MFT offset: 6293504, MFT mirror offset: 2064)
```

If you let Testdisk run on 100% of the drive, it will find the partition. You can then use Testdisk to list the files and extract them. It might be possible that it can even recover the backup NTFS boot sector or you could do it manually by flashing it on the first sector of the partition.